# Windows Media Center stopped working after replacing motherboard

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, windows-media-center

The motherboard on my Dell 9100 Studio XPS finally died, I ended up buying a used 9100 motherboard online.  I swapped out the boards and fired it up without any problems.  All of my programs launch fine with the exception of Windows Media Center, when I launch it the TV plays for five seconds then I get the message, “Copying Prohibited ; The broadcaster prohibits this content from being copied.  You can only play this content on the same computer on which it was recorded”.  I assume that Windows Media Center is keyed to the bios of the motherboard; does anyone know a work around for this?  I am running Windows7 Professional.  Thank  you.